# How can I open this Spring project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, rest

Silly question, cant seem to get it to work.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ mentions a Java project - available here on GIT - https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git and here directly - https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/archive/master.zip .

When I try to import the zip, it fails. I tried to unzip and import selecting the root folder at source and it won't work.

How can I open this project in Eclipse and make my own changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple... Its a maven project ... go to import and try to import existing maven project...

Comment: I'm using STS spring Tool Suite and i managed to import it as a Gradle project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ensure that you are selecting "Existing Maven Project"

File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Project
Point to the inflated directory and choose the pom.xmls

Comment: Perfect, thank you, never worked with a MVN project before and didnt realise it had it's own option. Much appreciated. Will accept this in 3 minutes when it is possible to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With Eclipse Neon, `File > Open Projects from Filesystem...` , select `Archive` and give location of your zip, click `Finish`.